# Warning: Massive error in json_encode()

Tags: php, ajax, json

```
<?php  
$int = 1968401665333658496;  
echo json_encode( array("$int",$int) );  
?>
```

Recieved in browser: `[ "1968401665333658496"  ,  1968401665333658600 ]`

It "rounds off" my integer?

Btw : `PHP_INT_MAX = 9223372036854775807 ~ PHP Version 5.3.2-1ubuntu4.7`
No problems with these huge integers anywhere (PHP, MySQL or Javascript)
- until `json_encode(`) screws it up (silently btw..)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Javascript has no concept of integers, according to the standard all numbers are IEEE doubles, which means they have 52 bits of mantissa. this leads to a practical maximum "integer" value of `2^53` before any loss of precision.

I am not sure how you didn't have problems with numbers this large in JS alone - if you didn't your JS implementation is not standards compliant.

Comment: Wow, that's sobering. Having worked professionally with JS, not knowing such a basic fact.  Still 2^53 = 9007199254740992, still leaves me plenty of wriggleroom for my (8 types of) unique-key scheme : )  THANK YOU!

Answer (score 4):

It's not just a JSON issue. If you put

```
alert(1968401665333658496);
```

in firebug console you get `1968401665333658600`

You're probably hitting the JS max value.

There's a discussion on that here : [What is JavaScript's highest integer value that a Number can go to without losing precision?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/307179/)

Comment: OK, I may have been a bit hasty, claiming "no problem" in javascript :)

Answer (score 1):

Quote your integer value and handle the conversion on the client.

Comment: this will not help at all - this number is larger than what a standards compliant JS implementation can handle without loss of precision.

Comment: If you knew it wouldn't make any difference why did you suggest it?

Comment: OP doesn't need an INT it's a "unique key scheme", don't see why it can't be a string.

Comment: If you need big integers, you can handle the conversion on the client: http://jsfromhell.com/classes/bignumber

Comment: That truly looks like JS from HELL - good to know this class exists. Thank you Diodeus